# Converting double qouted string to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string like:

```
var jsonStr = "{"option":"option value","response":"response value","order":3}";
```

When I convert it to json object like this:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

It gives an `SyntaxError`. But if declare the string with single quotes like this:

```
var jsonStr = '{"option":"option value","response":"response value","order":3}';
```

It works fine. The problem is the string comes from the server with double quotes. How can I parse this?

Comment: "{"option:  another quote  is missing ...

Comment: Why not serialize in the server and pass the json already serialized?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error is in the JavaScript string literal:

```
var jsonStr = "{"option:"option value","response":"response value","order":3}";
                 ^ The error is here
```

It never reaches `JSON.parse(jsonStr)`, the script has already aborted by then.

You can't fix it from JavaScript because a script cannot rewrite its own source code after it has thrown an exception and died.

You have to fix this on the server.

Comment: @suheb This answer still applies, even with the updated json string.

Answer (score 0):

the error is how the supposedly json string is written.

```
var jsonStr = "{"option":"option value","response":"response value","order":3}"
```

javascript does not read your jsonStr as a String instead it throws an error before reaching this line `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);`

you can also remove the opening and closing quote. Then, check if it's already an object before parsing

```
var jsonStr = {"option":"option value","response":"response value","order":3};
var jsonObj = typeof jsonStr != 'object' ? JSON.parse(jsonStr) : jsonStr;
```